# MVC 5, EF 6 Barebones Invalid Column Name 'Model'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After fighting this in a project mixing webforms and MVC, I have now started an empty project and still see "Invalid Column Name 'Model'. error.  The barebones test project is as follows:

VS2012 -> New Project -> ASP.NET MVC 5 Empty Project (Visual C#), named it testef

My Data Context **NosContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace testef.Domain_Models
{
    public class NosContext : DbContext
    {
        public NosContext() : base("Name=NosContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Nos_Templates> Templates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My only model, **Nos_Templates.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace testef.Domain_Models
{
    public class Nos_Templates
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string template_name { get; set; }
        public string edit_region { get; set; }
        public string question_list { get; set; }
        public DateTime? create_date { get; set; }
        public Guid? creating_user { get; set; }
        public DateTime? update_date { get; set; }
        public Guid? updating_user { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The index method of controller **HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using testef.Domain_Models;

namespace testef.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private NosContext db = new NosContext();

        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Templates.ToList());
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And connection string in **web.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NosContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And finally the structure of the table in the DB

```
id               uniqueidentifier   NotNull
template_name    varchar(150)       Nullable
edit_region      ntext              Nullable
question_list    ntext              Nullable
create_date      datetime           Nullable
creating_user    uniqueidentifier   Nullable
update_date      datetime           Nullable
updating_user    unique identifier  Nullable
```

When the controller executes **return View(db.Templates.ToList());** it throws the exception -

"Invalid column name 'Model'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Model'."

I can take the generated SQL code (as grabbed from within the VS exception handler) and run against the DB in Sql manager studio and it works just fine.

I don't understand the error as it acts like I've specified a column in the model that does not exist in the database table or have something in the table that does not exist in the model.  I have tried creating by hand and by reverse engineering code-first and same error no matter.

Any ideas why it's throwing an error on non-existent column like this?

**UPDATE**

I did a generate script to script the table to new query window and created a new DB called testEF and ran the create script to generate the table in question.  This new DB works just fine without the error. This **does not**  explain why it doesn't work on the existing db/table - even when running said script to drop/create the table in the DB that is not working.  So it appears something is amiss in SQL and not the code.

**UPDATE 2**

There were a couple items out of skew

- The original DB creator did not define any primary keys, so it didn't play nice and EF had a hard time I guess due to this.
- Using the Code First tools was not generating a proper connection string (I did not change anything, but I am now getting this properly) H/T to @Uber Bot for this.

After defining proper keys and re-running the code first existing db EF tools, I have proper model and connection strings and it works, both in new solution and existing solution where it initial was not working.

Thanks for all the insight and tips.

Comment: Try to run SQL Server Profiler to see what SQL statements exactly does EF generate.

Comment: SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[template_name] AS [template_name], 
    [Extent1].[edit_region] AS [edit_region], 
    [Extent1].[question_list] AS [question_list], 
    [Extent1].[create_date] AS [create_date], 
    [Extent1].[creating_user] AS [creating_user], 
    [Extent1].[update_date] AS [update_date], 
    [Extent1].[updating_user] AS [updating_user]
    FROM [dbo].[Nos_Templates] AS [Extent1]

As you can see, the field Model is not there, or anywhere, but it keeps trying to use it.

Comment: @SouthPlatte Are you using MSSQL or MySQL?

Comment: Is this connecting to a database that already exists?

Comment: MSSQL, and yes database already exists.

Comment: And if you take the SQL you posted in the comment above, running that manually works fine?

Comment: Yes DavidG, copy/paste into SQL manager studio it runs fine.

Comment: Then there must be some other code you are not showing us. What you have posted cannot possibly generate that error on it's own.

Comment: DavidG I wish that were the case.  I will gladly zip the sample solution (I made it 10 minutes prior to posting this question) up and send via email, dropbox, github etc. to anyone along with the SQL script to create the table for any insight on this. In fact, I will create the SQL script to create the empty DB, populate a single row in the table for testing, then upload it all to GitHub for review this evening - I will post a comment when I have done so.

Comment: @SouthPlatte Probably something wrong with your table. Can you upload the solution somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add additional fields to the generated model, you should create a partial class for example:

you have this generated class:

```
    public partial class Nos_Templates
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string template_name { get; set; }
        public string edit_region { get; set; }
        public string question_list { get; set; }
        public DateTime? create_date { get; set; }
        public Guid? creating_user { get; set; }
        public DateTime? update_date { get; set; }
        public Guid? updating_user { get; set; }
    }
```

To add an additional field you should do this:

```
    public partial class Nos_Templates
    {
        public string testField { get; set; }   
    }
```

Comment: I'm not adding additional fields and using the partial keyword changed nothing.  EF is claiming I am trying to select the field named 'Model' which is clearly not anywhere in my code, my table definition or anywhere.  That's what I don't understand is where EF is getting a ghost field reference from.

Comment: Judging from the connection string it appears to be Code-First.

Comment: It began as code first in the primary project before I pulled it into this test project.  I did code first reverse engineer existing DB.  There are no relationships defined at this time either to any of the other three tables I would like to work with eventually.

Comment: So it is not code first now? In that case you need to revise your connection string to include metadata. e.g. metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It says MetaData is only required if the Name attribute is not specified, which mine is and I do not have a .csdl, .ssdl or .msl file anywhere to be found in this or the project I recreated it from.

I originally did Code First reverse engineer for the 4 tables, but it failed from the very get with this exact error.  Same if I build it manually by hand, which is the example here.  I can post a clean project using reverse engineer code first but I already know it will fail with the same error in the same way.

Comment: Just created a blank project using code you supplied. It works. The problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies.  It appears there is an issue in the table in the original DB.  I did a create to -> script and ran it on a clean DB and the solution works without issue.  So going to drop/recreate the tables in the existing DB and then rebuild and go from there.

If I find the culprit in the DB table I will post the findings just in case someone else has the same issue.